# Using Google ReCaptcha on Domain Paths

Tags: path, dns, recaptcha

I have searched around for a solution but haven't been able to find anything. Hopefully you can help me!

I am trying to implement Google ReCaptcha V3 on a few Wordpress websites under the subdomain: staging.cascading-styles.com. From there I would like to use it on specific paths of this domain for example staging.cascading-styles.com/gordonamacqueen.

I was hopeful that I could just enter the subdomain (without the path) into Google Admin Console when registering a new site, and use the same keys on all staging sites. This did not work however and I ended up locking myself out (fixed now). Google will not let me enter a URL with a path.

Is it possible to use ReCaptcha with this kind of URL? Thanks in advance.